# How to add new email addresses from google form (sheets) to googlegroups email list?

Tags: email, mailing-list, google-groups

I have a google form on my site that collects user info, including email addresses.
I have already created a script that sends a welcome email.
Now I need to be able to create an email list from that list of emails.
The resulting email list will be receiving triggers from IFTTT to send an email with particular triggers.
How do I get the email addresses from the form results (google sheets) to the mailing list (currently in googlegroups)?
The email list should be able to be triggered with a single address (something@googlegroups.com) because that's all IFTTT will allow.
(I'm working on a test process for a tech company. While we refine details of the app's function, which I am not building, we also want to test the real-world end of the process, and make it as simple and user-friendly as possible.)